# Set of $v$ such that $v \in W $ and $Av \in W $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let A be an $n\times n$ matrix of rank $n$, and $W$ a non-trivial subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

What is the set of vectors $v$ such that $v \in W $ and $Av \in W $?

Is this a simple problem?

Comment: Otherwise stated, this is $W\cap A^{-1}W$. It depends heavily on $W$ and $A$. It could be $W$, $\{0\}$, ...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a particularly simple problem and I will not go into great detail. For a good introduction to the subject, I suggest you take a look at Chapter 2 of [this book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=LtbM8Ph1dnIC&pg=PA45&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false). I will call the set of vectors satisfying your condition $S$.

Basically, you are after the maximal $A$-invariant subspace in $W$. Let $V$ denote the maximally $A$-invariant subspace of $W$.

Let $U\subseteq W$ be any $A$-invariant subspace in $W$. Then clearly for each $\mathbf{v}\in U \subseteq W$ we have $A\mathbf{v} \in U\subseteq W$. Therefore the set $S$ you are after contains every $A$-invariant subspace of $W$ and specifically it contains the maximal such subspace, $V\subseteq S$.

Conversely, suppose that $V$ is the maximal $A$-invariant subspace of $W$ (the fact that such a subspace exists and is unique we take for granted, although it is proven in the book). Suppose there is some vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $\mathbf{v}\in S$ but $\mathbf{v}\notin V$. Then $\langle \mathbf{v}\rangle$ is a one-dimensional $A$-invariant subspace of $W$ independent from $V$. Therefore $V\oplus \langle\mathbf{v}\rangle$ is a $A$-invariant subspace which properly contains $V$, contrary to the fact that $V$ is maximal. This is a contradiction. Therefore $S\subseteq V$.

Now let $B$ be an operator $B:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\ker(B)=W$. Then the maximally $A$-invariant subspace of $W$ is given by
$$V=\bigcap^{n-1}_{k=0} \ker(BA^k)$$
Again, I direct you towards the book linked above for a proof of this statement.

Comment: How do you define the maximal $A$-invariant subspace in $W$? There is probably something obvious I can't see.

Comment: @julien The $A$-invariant subspace of $W$ with maximal dimension. Clearly the set of $A$-invariant subspaces is non-empty since $\{\mathbf{0}\}\in W$. The dimension is bounded above by $\dim W$ so there exists an $A$-invariant subspace of maximum dimension in $W$. This subspace is uniquely defined. Take a look at 2.7 in the book I link, this answer is pretty much an exposition from that section.

Comment: I see why there is a maximal such subspace. But I don't why there is only one.

Comment: @julien If there were two such that $V_1 \neq V_2$ then $V_1 + V_2$ is invariant and properly contains each. This contradicts maximality.

Comment: Ah! Yes, of course, sorry. So another way to argue is to consider the span of all $A$ invariant subspaces. This obviously defines the maximal one.

Comment: The reference looks most relevant. One immediate question: is it possible, perhaps under some assumptions A or W, to reach simple conclusions on how the dimension of V depends on the interaction between A and W? Any hints appreciated.

Comment: @mark I really doubt that there will be an easy relationship. It really depends on what you're after. Is there a particular case  that you're interested in?

Comment: Yes, my particular case is:
(i) $A$ has exactly 3 eigenspaces: $E_1$ and $E_2$ of dimension 1 and $E_3$ of dimension $n-2$;
(ii) $E_3$ is also an eigenspace of $A^T$;
(iii) there is a vector, the vector of all ones in my application, that belongs to both $W$ and  $E_1 \oplus E_2$.

From numerical experiments it seems that (when no other relation between $A$ and $W$ is imposed, e.g., $W$ does not contain eigenvectors of $A$) $$\mathrm{dim}(S)=\mathrm{dim}(W)-1,$$ but I don't understand why.

Comment: It would be good to have more information (for example, is the dimension of $W$ determined?). But for now here are a few observations. $W$ as a subspace either contains both $E_1$ and $E_2$ or neither. When it contains both $E_1$ and $E_2$ then $W$ itself will be an invariant subspace so $\dim(S) = \dim(W)$. We can assume then that your $W$ generally does not contain either $E_1$ or $E_2$. Any invariant subspace containing your vector of ones will necessarily contain $E_1$ and $E_2$. This means that any invariant subspace of $W$ must not contain the vector and hence $\dim(S) \le \dim(W)-1$.

Comment: In fact, I suspect that your $W$ is of the form $$W = \langle\mathbf{v}\rangle \oplus E_3^\prime$$ where $\mathbf{v}$ is your vector of all ones (or any vector belonging to both $W$ and $E_1 \oplus E_2$) and $E_3^\prime\subseteq E_3$ is a subspace of $E_3$. In this case, the largest invariant subspace of $W$ is simply $E_3^\prime$ which clearly has dimension one less than $W$. I am not entirely sure if $W$ is forced into this structure, but I suspect so. I do not have time right now, but I will take a look later.

Comment: Your approach seems very powerful. I cannot see why $W$ should have that form though, so any explanation/intuition would be very helpful

Comment: @EuYu I forgot to answer the question in your previous comment. I'm trying to understand what $\mathrm{dim}(S)$ is for a given $\mathrm{dim}(W)$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one computational approach to this problem is to come up with an orthonormal basis $w_1, ..., w_k, v_{k+1}, ..., v_n$ where the $w_i$ are an orthonormal basis for $W$ and the remaining vectors are an orthonormal basis for $W^\perp$. Then your problem reduces to solving the system of equations:

$\sum_{i=1}^k a_i v_j^T A w_i = 0$

For $j = 1, ..., (n-k)$. There are $k$ coefficients $a_i$, and there are $(n-k)$ equations, so basically it comes down to finding the null-space of some $(n-k) \times k$ matrix. One efficient way to compute a null-space is with SVD. It can also be done with QR decomposition, or even just with row-reduction.

Once you have a basis for the null-space of the matrix $(v_j^T A w_i)$, these vectors become coefficients for vectors of the form $\sum a_i w_i$ which themselves form a basis for the vector subspace $W \cap A^{-1}(W)$.

Comment: Didn't you mean $W\cap A^{-1}W$?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I made a lot of typos actually, but hopefully they're all gone.